# What is an F-word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an F-word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| F-words™ | Not F-words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABRACADABRA | APPLES |
| BALLS | BROWNIE |
| CORN | COOKIES |
| DABBING | DUCKY |
| ELMO | ELEVATOR |
| FABRIC | FURY |
| GAGGING | GORILLA |
| HAMMER | HANDWRITE |
| INDIGO | IZZIE |
| JEWEL | JOLLY |
| KISS | KICKING |

CSV Version:

```
F-words™,Not F-words™
ABRACADABRA,APPLES
BALLS,BROWNIE
CORN,COOKIES
DABBING,DUCKY
ELMO,ELEVATOR
FABRIC,FURY
GAGGING,GORILLA
HAMMER,HANDWRITE
INDIGO,IZZIE
JEWEL,JOLLY
KISS,KICKING
```

These are not the only examples of F-words™, many more exist.

Note:

> I will add one row to this puzzle each day it remains unsolved, up to the letter Z.

Comment: By the way, the word that is usually known as the "F-word" **is** an F-word™ :p

Comment: Ferret, you mean, right?  Or did you mean the really bad rude one ... *fart*?!

Comment: \*gasps* $\!\!$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

F-words are ...

> words whose numerical values scores are below 60, that is, an F.
>  The numerical value of a word is the total of all its letter values, where A=1, B=2, C=3, ... , Z=26.

Comment: I (and probably others) would have had this days ago without the COOKIE error :)

Comment: sorry about that